# ASP.Net MVC 4 Display Single Row of Data using button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 4 application and trying to display a single row of data from the data base instead of all rows.

The website I am designing has a list of buttons and when each button is clicked the data from the corresponding row in the database is displayed e.g. Button1 - Row1, Button2 - Row2 etc...

Currently this is also displayed on `http://myexample/Movies/OneMovie` I would like it to be displayed on `http://myexample/Movies/`

The code I have in my controller is this:

```
public ActionResult OneMovie(int id = 0)
{
    Movie movie = db.Movies.Single(m => m.ID == id);

    if (movie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(movie);
}
```

The button for my code is:

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" name="id"/>
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" name="id"/>
```

Can anyone help me to display my data for the corresponding row when the button is clicked?

Comment: Are you wanting to redirect to a view to display the details, or display the details on the same page?

Comment: there are a lot of ways to do that. Do you mean how to call "OneMovie" from button or ?

Comment: I would like the data to be displayed on the same page as the button. Current its goes to Movies/OneMovie, I would like to be on the Movies which in the index page.

Comment: If you want to be able to open all rows in the same screen, I would load all the buttons and rows in the view and open the rows using javascript or jquery.

Comment: The idea is that the data will display in a div when the corresponding button is clicked.

Comment: In jQuery you can set no-display class on the row and after click button remove class no-display

Comment: @JeroenDop how can this be done? As my data is coming from an SQL database!

Comment: Instead of getting one row get all the rows from the database.(or at least the ones you need). Return a list of movies to the view. In the view create a for loop that creates a button and a row. On the button you add a javascript function onclick=buttonClicked(rowID). In javascript you add a function buttonClicked(id) In that function you look for the row with the same id and set display none or display block

Comment: @JeroenDop can you display this code as an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

ok then when you generate the buttons you loop a collection just to get the id's of all movies, here is the button that you need :

```
<input type="button" value="Go Somewhere Else" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("OneMovie", "ControllerName", new { id=1  } )'" />
```

set into your view **id= model.MovieId**

this will allow you to make a get request at the action:

```
    public ActionResult OneMovie(int id)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

**Edit for a ajax get solution**

in your index page:

```
function getMovieById(movieId) {
    var url = "/Home/OneMovie";
    $.getJSON(url, { id: "movieId"}, function (data) {
        /*
        put movie into div here
        */
    });
}
```

your button will be like:

```
<input type="button" value="Go Somewhere Else" onclick=getMovieById(1) />
```

and the action:

```
public JsonResult OneMovie(int Id)
{
...
var items = db.Movies.Where...
return Json(items , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Can I use in the Index the same way as OneMovie?

Comment: Currently I can't display any data on my index page. In which I had this piece of code - return View(db.Movies.ToList());

Comment: the Index is supposed to be called from URL. in what I understand I think you can go for something like:
In index load, you load the first movie and the buttons for all of them. then on each button click you display some partial view in that part of div you were working on.

Comment: I would like the data to be displayed on the same page as the button.

Comment: yes, that's why I said a partial view. Or you can go for a JSON solution.

Comment: can you amend the above solution to show this for the index with multiple buttons?

Comment: Thanks, just as the link above takes you to a separate page where as I would like the data to be displayed below in a div :)

Comment: Hi, I am very confused with the ajax solution of where the code goes. Is there a way to do this on the same index page without using ajax?

Comment: always there will be other ways of doing something, notice that MVC pattern has a different way of thinking that Event-Driven pattern, and loading all movies and hiding them is heavy duty for that action, just think of loading at one GET request X objects. What are you missing from the script solution ?

Comment: This is currently done on a new page call onemovie and I would like it on the index page. Is the action command complete?>

Comment: yes, you do it just like that and then in the section "put the movie into div here"   you read the JSON object like __$("#labelMovieName").val(  data.Name)__

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109569/discussion-between-e-b-and-terrortot38).

Comment: more than happy to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MoviesModel
{
     public List<Movie> Movies  {get;set;}
}

    //get all movies and return to view
    public ActionResult AllMovies()
    {       
       MoviesModel model=new MoviesModel();
       model.Movies=  db.Movies.ToList();
        if (model.Movies== null || model.Movies.Count==0)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(model);
    }


//html view
    @model MoviesModel
    @foreach(var movie in Model.Movies){
       <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" name="movie.Id" onclick="ButtonClicked(movie.Id)"/>
       <div class="hidden" id='movie.Id'>
          <span>...movie info...</span>
       </div>
    }

//javascript

function ButtonClicked(id)
{
   var element= Document.GetEllementById(id)
  //set css class visible 
}


//CSS
.visible
{
display:block;
}

.hide
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: I have just tried this solution but how does it work using a button?

Comment: This is roughly the setup, don't have a MVC project open here. But i think it should work on anything...you just need the onclick event. If you use jquery you can also add a little bit of animation